# C# : How to report progress while creating a zip file?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, dotnetzip

Update: Got it working updated my working code

Here is what I have so far

```
 private async void ZipIt(string src, string dest)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {
                // add content to zip here 
                zipFile.AddDirectory(src);
                zipFile.SaveProgress +=
                    (o, args) =>
                    {
                        var percentage = (int)(1.0d / args.TotalBytesToTransfer * args.BytesTransferred * 100.0d);
                        // report your progress
                        pbCurrentFile.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {

                                pbCurrentFile.Value = percentage;
                            }
                            ));
                    };
                zipFile.Save(dest);
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to figure out how to update my progress bar but not sure if I am on the right track I have searched around and found many examples for windows forms and vb.net but nothing for wpf c# was wondering if anyone could help.

Comment: _Update: Got it working updated my working code_ - This is a __really__ bad idea! You can append working code but changing/fixing the original code so that it doesn't fit your question or the comments and answers any longer is not recommended!

Comment: Related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430559/progress-bar-not-available-for-zipfile-how-to-give-feedback-when-program-seems. If progress-reporting is the only feature needed from the DotNetZip library, this is easy enough to implement using the .NET .zip archive classes directly, without taking on the extra dependency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I guess you are using DotNetZip ?**

There are numerous issue in the code you've shown:

- you don't call [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress) in `DoWork` so how do you expect to get the progress ?
- even if you did so the problem is with `zip.Save()` you wouldn't get a progress (beside 100%) because it would not return unless it is finished.

**Solution**

Use tasks and `SaveProgress` event instead :

```
private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
        {
            // add content to zip here 
            zipFile.SaveProgress +=
                (o, args) =>
                {
                    var percentage = (int) (1.0d/args.TotalBytesToTransfer*args.BytesTransferred*100.0d);
                    // report your progress
                };
            zipFile.Save();
        }
    });
}
```

**Doing this way, your UI will not freeze and you will get a periodic report of the progress.**

Always prefer Tasks over `BackgroundWorker` since it's *official* approach to use now.

Comment: Am using native .net System.IO.Compression

Comment: @KishoreSahas: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430559/progress-bar-not-available-for-zipfile-how-to-give-feedback-when-program-seems