# Zip the folder with ProgressBar in C#

Tags: c#

I have a zipping code where I need to provide a progressbar. I tried checking in internet about how to do it. but, I didnt get any answer for that.

Any suggestions to this will be highly appreciated.

**Code for Zipping**

```
label1.Text = "Compression started.";
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(destFolder, Backup + "\\VibrantBackup" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh.mm.ss") + ".zip");
label1.Text = "Compression completed.";
```

Comment: If you just search for `C# progress bar` you will instantly get at least 3 good results.

Comment: `ZipFile.CreateZipFromDirectory` does not support progress bar. Try to use some external library to do this stuff e.g. DotNetZip. Maybe it can help you

Comment: [Look this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976841/how-to-report-progress-while-creating-a-zip-file)

Comment: You are using `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`? If so, I don't agree with the marked duplicate which is linking to a question about a completely different library.